# Is there difference between two for form in C++?

Tags: c++

```
vector<int> a;
```

1.

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
```

2.

```
vector<int>::iterator end = a.end();
for(vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != end; ++it)
```

which is more efficient？or the same?

Comment: 2nd form can be better written as: `for(vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(), end = a.end(); it != end; ++it)`

Answer (score 10):

Initial criticisms:

1/ **Typical tutorial example**

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it)
```

There is no magic, but it brings up a question: is `a` ever modified in the loop that the end bound may vary ?

2/ **Improved**

```
vector<int>::iterator end = a.end();
for(vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(); it != end; ++it)
```

`a.end()` is only executed once, it seems. However since `end` is not `const`, it may be modified inside the loop.

Furthermore, it introduces the `end` identifier in the outer scope, polluting it.

So there is a potential gain in performance, but not much in clarity. Also, it's far more verbose.

---

I would propose several other ways:

3/ **Best Manual**

```
for(vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin(), end = a.end(); it != end; ++it)
```

Combines the advantages of `v1` (quite terse, no outer scope pollution) and `v2` (performance), however it is still unclear if `end` is ever modified within the loop body.

4/ **Boost-powered**

```
BOOST_FOREACH(int& i, a)
```

Even terser than `v1`, immediately identifiable at a glance, no outer scope leak, and guarantee of full iteration (it's not possible to modify the bounds).

Unfortunately:

- there are issues with commas in the type of the variable (because it relies on the preprocessor)
- compile-time errors are completely cryptic (because it relies on the preprocessor)

*Note: in theory, one could make the case of the `std::foreach` algorithm here, but honestly... there is too much effort involved in defining a predicate outside and it breaks code locality.*

5/ **C++11 range-for statement**

```
for (int& i: a)
```

All the advantages:

- Extremely Terse
- As performant as the best C++ hand-written loop
- Guaranteed full iteration, no questions asked

And none of the issues (scope leak, preprocessor magic).

---

Personally, I use C++11 range-for whenever I can (hobby projects) and `BOOST_FOREACH` otherwise (at work).

I avoid like the plague modifying the container I am iterating on, preferring to rely on STL algorithms when I need to filter/remove elements... It's too easy to mess up with the boundary conditions and iterator invalidations otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

2nd is more efficient as it only requires creating the end iterator once.

A smart compiler may optimize the first one to be the second, but you cannot be guaranteed that that will happen.

It would actually be a bit of a complicated optimization because the compiler would need to be 100% certain that any subsequent call to end() will have no additional effects or return anything different.  Basically, it would need to know that at least over the loop, end() always returns something such that end() == previous call to end().  Whether or not compilers do that optimization is not guaranteed.

Comment: Don't agree that compiler can optimize 1st way to be of second, as the vector can be changed in the body. It might not be legal to change vector inside the loop though!

Comment: If the compiler is smart enough, it will know that the vector is not altered inside of the loop.  That much analysis would be getting into the realm of carried away, but considering how often this idiom is used, and considering most compilers are bundled with their own implementation of the C++ standard library, I wouldn't be surprised if compilers do look for this optimization.

Comment: @tuxuday In short -- Possible, yes.  Definite: no.  (Edit: You are right though that if the vector is modified, then the compiler definitely cannot optimize that)

Comment: If the **end()** routine returns constant value then for sure compiler can optimize. If it doesn't then its **impossible** to optimize. **vector.end()** seems to returns non-constant value.

Comment: No, even if it's return were constant it would not be definitely possible without analyzing more.  What if end() had a side effect?  Then even if the return was const it still could not be optimized.  What I'm saying is that the compiler would have to analyze the code to ensure that subsequent calls to end() would return the same thing.   The compiler is not depending on language features in this situation, it's depending on static analysis.

Comment: I don't accept with you. Lets assume if **end()** returns **NULL** then for sure compile can replace **end()** with **NULL**. How you see otherwise?

Comment: I'm sorry, @tuxuday, but I'm not sure how else I can explain this.  Basically the compiler can do voodoo magic, mathematically prove that for all iterations of the loop all calls to end() will == each other.  It's not exactly a simple task considering all of the possibilities that the compiler must examine.  But yes, it *is* possible.

Comment: @tuxuday: there are several conditions to optimize away a function call. The first is that the compiler should know (or infer) that the function has no side effect, the second is that it should know (or infer) that the function will return the same value each time. First is usually provable for templates, however here second is not so easy: if you pass a reference to the vector (even a const reference) to another function within the loop body, then how can the compiler know that this function does not modify the vector in any way ?

Comment: FWIW: I did a set of measurements some time ago (with g++), and at that time, calling `end()` once, before the loop, rather than each time in the loop, did make a difference (whereas there was no difference between `++ iter` and `iter ++`).  A more intelligent compiler could optimize out the unnecessary calls.  Especially if it embedded knowledge about `std::vector`.  (Almost anything you do which might change `end()` will also invalidate `it`, resulting in undefined behavior.)

Comment: One other comment concerning optimization: `std::vector<>::end()` is almost certainly an inline function, so the compiler knows exactly what is going on.  Typically, it returns a pointer member of the object.  All the compiler needs to do to hoist the evaluation of `end()` out of the loop is to determine that this pointer is never modified in the loop.  For simple loops, this is well within the scope of well known optimization techniques (and for complicated loops, the extra pointer read is irrelevant).

Comment: @Matthieu M., You are right. But you are generalizing. Let us discuss about **end()** alone. If **end()** is simple like void ***end(){ return (void***)NULL;}?

Comment: @JamesKanze Interesting.  I would have thought that g++ would optimize out the extra end() calls for a simple loop.

Comment: @tuxuday That return statement makes no sense.

Comment: Yeah issue with formatting.Let me try again. void* end() { return (void*)NULL;} -- got it! :)

Comment: @Corbin Because the function is inline, I think it's just extra memory reads.  And for simple loops, I would expect so to, but it didn't.  Then, at least.  I'll have to find the code and redo the measurements, to see if things have improved.  (If in the loop you call a function which can also access the vector, then obviously the compiler can't do the optimization, but IIRC, all I was doing in the loop itself was `tot += *iter;`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Ah. And out of curiosity (not pedantry), could the compiler literally not do the optimization, or would it have to trace through the function and do a crap-ton of analysis?  (I'm thinking it would just have to do an unreasonable amount of analysis?)

Comment: @tuxuday A function that always return NULL would likely be completely optimized away by any decent compiler.  I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Corbin, thats my point. If you read my comments earlier it should be clear.

Comment: @tuxuday Right, but your logic doesn't make sense.  Your case is basically "The compiler can remove extra calls to a function that always returns the same thing.  end() does not always return the same thing.  Therefore, end() cannot be removed."   Sometimes end() does return the same thing though, and in those cases the extra calls can be removed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: FWIW LLVM will optimize the call away in simplistic situations.

Comment: @MatthieuM.When a vector is passed to a function as a const reference, why can't the compiler assume it won't change the vector (except of course for mutable members)? At least a change via const_cast is undefined behaviour, right?

Comment: @rafak For better or for worse, casting away const and then modifying the object is well defined, legal behavior according to the standard.  It's only when the object itself is const that undefined behavior occurs.

Comment: @Corbin The semantics of the standard library are defined by the standard, and the compiler is allowed to build this information in, so in theory, less analysis would be needed than for a user written type.  In practice, I know of no compiler which does this, so the question is somewhat academic.

Answer (score 1):

2nd way is obviously better, as it calls **a.end()** only once. In essence if there are **N** nodes in your tree then you save **N** calls to **a.end()**.

Comment: Doesn't he save N - 1 calls since he does make one call?

Comment: Actually he does save **N** calls. In the second case **end()** is called **N+1** times(For N nodes + failure condition)

Comment: Whether the difference in performance is significant depends.  It usually isn't, and the first example is idiomatic.  Which one is "better" thus depends on context.  In most cases, the first is, because it is idiomatic.  In specific applications, where performance is an issue, it may be worth universally adopting a different idiom; in such cases, I'd go with defining both the running iterator and `end` in the initialization part of the `for`.

Comment: @tuxday: Ah yea, true. I forgot about the failure attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first for loop is more certain. In case you insert/erase elements inside this for loop the `end` iterator you have defined is invalidated. For example:

```
vector<int>::iterator mend = int_vec.end(), mbegin = int_vec.begin();
while(mbegin != mend)
{
    cout << *mbegin << " ";
    int_vec.erase(mbegin);
    // mbegin is automatically invalidated
    // execution of this program causes bizarre runtime_error !
    // never try this at home !
}
```

A safer version of the code above could be this:

```
vector<int>::iterator mend = int_vec.end(), mbegin = int_vec.begin();
while(mbegin != mend)
{
    cout << *mbegin << " ";
    int_vec.erase(mbegin);
    mbegin = int_vec.begin(); // ok, mbegin updated.
}
```